# "NSUserDefaultsController"について

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Objective-Cのプログラミング概要のドキュメントを読んでいます。
その中で、"NSUserDefaultsController"というコントローラが出てきました。

こちらはどのような場面で活用するものでしょうか？

調べても具体的に記述されているところを発見できず、質問させていただきます。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

## 元資料

https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CocoaEncyclopedia.pdf

Comment: `ios`タグをつけていらっしゃいますが、`NSUserDefaultsController`は、`OS X`にはありますが、`iOS`にはありません。`ios`タグを外して、`osx`タグを代わりにつけることを、お勧めします。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。osxのコントローラだったんですね。ありがとうございます。
現在、iosアプリ制作ために当該資料を読み進めておりましたので、勘違いしておりました。
osxタグに修正させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

詳しい方から回答がつかないようなので、まったく詳しくない者ですが、知っている範囲のことをお話ししたいと思います。
Cocoa（OS X）とCocoa touch（iOS）には、データベースを扱う**Core Data**というフレームワークがあって、そのフレームワークの中に**Cocoa Binding**というものがあります。

[Core Data プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CoreData.pdf)（PDF書類）

これの118ページに、説明が載っています。Cocoa Bindingといっしょに使うオブジェクトとして、NSObjectController、NSArrayControllerが詳解されていますが、NSUserDefaultsControllerもそのひとつです。
Cocoa Bindingは、iOSで使えないため、NSUserDefaultsControllerも、iOSにありません。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
Cocoa Binding で使用するNSObject ということ理解いたしました。
引き続き精進いたします！